# Force Compile Error in Release Build but not Debug Build in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5

We have a situation where a piece of code we've written fails against a test instance of our database because of work yet undone in the database itself. (It's a patching issue on an AS/400 that is completely out of our control) We have to move forward with development and can using a hack for the code in question. We need to make sure that this hack never makes it into the production environment and were wondering if there was a way to make code build correctly when compiling for the Debug configuration but fail with a compiler error when the Release configuration is being built? I've started looking into the build configuration but have yet to find a good approach. Any ideas would be appreciated.

We're using VS 2008, C#, .Net 3.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use compiler directives like this:

```
#if !DEBUG
#error Must not make it into production
#endif
```

Ideally you would like to add a more complete comment describing *why* you can't let the hack go into production, detailing the steps or cases in your issue tracker that needs to be completed before it is safe, etc. etc.

Comment: Lasse . . . Thanks for the great (and quick) response. Works like a charm