# How to emit compiler errors for unfinished features in Release Mode for .NET code?

Tags: c#, .net

Being inspired by [this article](https://www.executeprogram.com/blog/the-code-is-the-to-do-list) I asked myself how can I emit compiler errors or , at least stop the build, if a feature is not implemented.

The only quick solution I came up with, is by creating a custom attribute:

```
    public class NoReleaseAttribute : System.Attribute
    {

        public NoReleaseAttribute()
        {
#if RELEASE
            .
#endif
        }
    }
```

The idea is to have a syntactic error somewhere, but only for Release. I used an attribute because the IDE will help me find quickly the references to the attribute, and thus all places that I marked as needed to be completed or fixed before going in production.

I don't like this solution because I want one to emit a compiler error in each place that needs attention, not a single global error elsewhere.

Perhaps there is a more fitted solution.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could clarify what sort of answer you're looking for. Do you definitely want it to be attribute-based? (If so, you might want to write a Roslyn analyzer.)

Comment: The easiest solution would be the one proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29279719/9363973), but depending on what exactly you want it may differ. I agree with Jon that a Roslyn analyzer might just be the way to go

Comment: Are you sure this is the right approach? Why are you committing placeholders for features that are not implemented? How do you avoid implementations that are just broken? Or forgetting to add the do-not-compile check? The normal approach would be to track implementation, review, and testing of features in a separate system. Such a system should show the status for the release.

Comment: @Jon Skeet, I don't need it to be attribute based. I want something that is terse and very easy to add/remove. Your suggestion might be what I need.

Comment: @MindSwipe I thought about preprocessor directives but I don't like to add lots of directives everywhere I need to stop building.

Comment: @JonasH by "features" I mean mini-features like a method implementation. Not complete features of the software. When I implement a feature (that is being tracked) I just sketch some classes or methods while defining the structure of the code to work on. Some things I implement on the spot while some things I leave to be done later because I want to focus on completing something else first. Using an external system would waste time.

Comment: I think what JonasH meant is, why are incomplete features even in a place where they could be installed productively? If you're in the process of sketching out a new area, and have some methods that aren't fully implemented yet, then why is this code even being considered to publish? If you're using a VCS, like git, then that code should live in it's own branch, and only be merged into the main or release branch once you actually finished implementing it. The "separate system" in this case is your git server in conjunction with a issue tracking system (either built into the server or external)

Comment: @MindSwipe, the code lives in Git, in its own branch. I just want another verification that anything that should have been implemented was taken care of.

Comment: I'd recommend you use `NotImplementedException` alongside `//TODO: Finish implementing this` comments and "outsource" the added verification step to a CI/CD pipeline and code review. Automatically reject pull requests if a `NotImplementedException` or a `TODO` (without explanation as to why the todo should be merged) or a failing (new) unittest is found. Much more automated and as such less likely to result in mistakes than manually adding something

Answer (score 1):

You may use **#error** directive in your code, it will cause an error at compile-time.

Example usage:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    DoSomeStuff();
}

#error Needs to be implemented
static void DoSomeStuff(){
    //This needs some work
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are no more fitted solution. You can use for your goal:

a) ObsoleteAttribute (may not fit your goal)

b) throw NotImplementedException in every place that you need to:

```
#if RELEASE
    throw new NotImplementedException();
#endif
```

c) Wrap throwing NotImplementedException with attribute as you described us.

Basically it is unnecessary to add code that will not be used anywhere - Visual Studio even marking this code with 0 usages and it will not be included in CIL. So you have to question yourself - do i *really* need useless code exist in our project? It is better to track unreleased features in tracking systems like YouTrack or something, than to search them in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a build step that checks the code for TODO-comments and generates warnings for them. A quick google suggest the [Warn About TODOs](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MattLaceyLtd.WarnAboutTODOs) extension might do just that, but it is not something I have used. You should also configure your build to fail on most warnings. A possible risk here is that people will just avoid using todo-comments, since they will fail the build.

But needing such a check suggest you do not have sufficient testing of your code. I find it a good practice to at least do *some* level of testing before committing any code, and just about any testing should reveal if entire components are not implemented. Reviewing your own code before committing is another practice that could be useful.

Automated unit testing can be a great way to deal with things like this. If you write unit tests for all your components the tests should find things like this, especially if you throw `NotImplementedException` in placeholders. This might require you to write your tests before the components, but there are certainly arguments for such a development approach.

The next line of defense should be code review. Even a quick review should find methods that are not implemented.

The final line of defense should be independent testing. If someone else tests the new features against the specification, any significant missing functionality should be found.